# Counter not work properly while using collection splitter mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I read data from salesforce and split it using collection splitter. I want to aggregate all data into single list. First I count all records and I set that counter with MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE. But my counter gives me wrong count..And my data didn't  aggregate..
How can I solve this problem

Is my following flow right?

Following is my code

```
<flow name="davesalesforceFlow1Tmp" doc:name="davesalesforceFlow1Tmp">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP" path="test" contentType="text/plain"  />
        <sfdc:query config-ref="salesforce" doc:name="Salesforce" query="My query"/>

        <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="cnt"
                          value="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.countMatches(message.payload, '\n') + org.mule.util.StringUtils.countMatches(message.payload, ',') - 1]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>

        <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE"
                  value="#[sessionVars.cnt]" doc:name="Property"/>
        <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
```

I also tried following code But in output got only single record

```
 <flow name="davesalesforceFlow1Tmp" doc:name="davesalesforceFlow1Tmp">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP" path="test" contentType="text/plain"  />
            <sfdc:query config-ref="salesforce" doc:name="Salesforce" query="My query"/>

            <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE"
                  value="#[message.outboundProperties['MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE']]" doc:name="Property"/>
            <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
<logger message="MY PAYLOAD IS  #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
  </flow>

    </flow>
```

Comment: You should see if the for each scope is a better fit for what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the collection splitter and aggregator together theres no need to keep track of the count or anything.

Mule will take care of this via the MULE_CORRELATION_* header behind the scenes.

Only if you are dong for complex splits and aggregates may you need to modify these headers yourself.

```
        <logger level="INFO" message="size before: #[payload.size()]" />

        <collection-splitter />

        <logger level="INFO" message="Individual item: #[payload]" />

        <collection-aggregator />

        <logger level="INFO" message="size after: #[payload.size()]" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it.. But didn't work..I have 10 records in SF. If i print in logger after collection-splitter then individual record display.But i want to aggregate them in single collection. After aggregating I got only one record. How can i aggregate all records????

Comment: Can you add the logs you're getting in the console please?